# Why does qty not take variables in the strategy.entry function?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

When I use strategy.entry - when i try to use qty = with a variable
strategy.entry just doesn't open any positions anymore.

```
sl = 70
balance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
riskperc = 4
maxusdloss = ( riskperc / 100 ) * balance
pipvalue = maxusdloss / sl
positionsize = pipvalue*(balance/sl)
strategy.entry (id = "long", direction=strategy.long, qty=positionsize, when = long_entry)
strategy.entry (id = "short", direction=strategy.short, qty=positionsize, when = short_entry)
strategy.exit (id = "exit-short", from_entry="short", qty=positionsize, stop = sl, profit = shorttp)
strategy.exit (id = "exit-long", from_entry="long", qty=positionsize, stop = -sl, profit = longtp)
```

Comment: please. Modify your post and add the code for the ```positionsize``` variable

Comment: Either value of `positionsize` argument is incorrect, or you don't have enough funds